# Codename One web.xml missing with web service wizard

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications, codenameone

When using the webservice wizard to create the server class, the required source java files are auto-generated and the method stubs need to be completed.

When deploying that web service, you can simply export the project as a WAR file and copy that to the webapps folder of your favorite web server (e.g. Tomcat).

Now, in my case I am using Maven to handle the dependencies. In this way though, the WAR export will not work, as the the required dependencies are not involved.
For Maven to properly package the project into a WAR file though, it requires a "web.xml" file in the WEB-INF folder.

How should that web.xml look like for the CN1 web service to be packaged by Maven into a WAR file?

thanks and BR

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of tomcat (I think since 7+) don't need a web XML. They have annotations for the servlets that handle all of the things that used to be in the web XML. If you look at the top of the servlet class you will see:

```
@WebServlet(name = "CN1WebServiceServlet", urlPatterns = {"/cn1proxy"})
```

That binds the servlet to the `cn1proxy` URL on your server.